# How do I Extend Zend View to Implement a Concrete Function?

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization

I want to make it as easy as possible for our designers to localise strings in views, which means that I want to do this:

```
...
<p><?php echo $this->_("Hello, world!"); ?></p>
...
```

The underscore notation here is necessary to allow Poedit to automagically extract all strings for localisation. The implementation is trivial:

```
public function _($string)
{
    return Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_($string);
}
```

At the moment, I've put this directly in `Zend_View_Abstract`, which is bad (I don't want to do this by modifying any of the Zend library). Ideally, then, I'd extend `Zend_View_Abstract` to allow me to implement other concrete functions that we require, but I don't know how to set this up. An alternative might be to implement a View Helper, but the only way that I know how to do this makes the code in the view more verbose. Any pointers (no, not those kind) would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think what I want to do is extend Zend_View_Abstract and use that new custom view in place of the view that the ViewRenderer uses, and there's no information out there about how to do this in a non-hackish way with the latest release of Zend. The Zend documentation unhelpfully mentions that "Many developers find that they want to extend Zend_View_Abstract to add custom functionality" without mentioning how to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously ignore my paths for your own...

1. Extend `Zend_View`
2. Put your method in this extended class
3. Instantiate the class (in your bootstrap for instance)
4. Assign it to the ViewRenderer
5. Pass that viewrenderer to `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker's` addHelper method
6. Use it in your view

In /library/MegaHAL/Zend/ create View.php:

```
class MegaHAL_Zend_View extends Zend_View
{
    public function _($string)
    {
    return Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_($string);
    }
}
```

In your bootstrap:

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH.'../library/MegaHAL/Zend/View.php';

$view = new MegaHAL_Zend_View();

$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
```

In your view:

```
<p><?php echo $this->_("Hello");?></p>
```

I believe that will do what you want, yes?

Comment: Works a treat - thanks for your help. I'm accepting this over other answers because it's more step-by-step, and specific to my problem with ViewRenderer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I tend to prefer more detailed explanations because the "one, two skip a few" type of instructions, like in the Zend Framework documentation, always seem to end up leaving out that one, tiny little nugget that ties it all together... drives me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're looking for a way to create [custom view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom).

Example:

```
class My_View_Helper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function translate($string)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

...

```
$view->setHelperPath('/path/to/helpers', 'My_View_Helper');
```

...

Then in your views you can use it:

```
echo $this->translate("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: I don't want to use a helper, because there doesn't seem to be any way for me to implement a function named "_" in a helper, due to the requirements of class naming and file naming (mentioned in the documentation you linked to). As I said in my question, the underscore notation is important, both for terseness, consistency with gettext, and Poedit automagic string extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think that using view helpers would be the correct "Zend-Framework"-way of doing this, you can extend `Zend_View` and implement all additional methods you'd like to have - this way you don't loose the features of `Zend_View`.

```
class My_View extends Zend_View
{
    public function _($string)
    {
        return Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_($string);
    }
}
```

You then only have to make sure that your new view class is instantiated and registered as the default view in the [controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration) (setting the `Zend_Controller_Action::$view` instance variable to an instance of your class) and in your [`Zend_Layout`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.options.html) (when using layouts; passing your view as a config option with key `view`) when not using the `ViewRenderer` or in the [`ViewRenderer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer) when using the `ViewRenderer` using `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer::setView()`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If configured properly Poedit can automatically extract strings from functions other than _().

Comment: Yes, you're quite right - but I still want to expose a concrete helper function to all views. Is it even possible?